# Change TileMap during gameLoop in Java

Tags: java, tile

I'm currently creating a game in java and I have reached a dead end. My game is a simple 2d shooting game with help of a TileMap **(.txt)** to create the "play-field" or "maze". Where I'm currently at is as you win (eliminating the enemies) the current TileMap should change to the next. The system I currently have works, but only from map 1 to 2 not 2 to 3.

This is what I got so far.

```
public class Frame extends JFrame implements KeyListener {

Hero hero;
    int lvl = 0;
    [...]
    won = false;
    String[] Maze = {"maze1", "maze2", "maze3", "maze4"};
    [...]

    public Frame(){

        Frame options
        [...]

        addKeyListener(this);

        gameLoop();

        if(won){

            if(GameState.ENEMIE_LIFE < 1)
                GameState.ENEMIE_LIFE = 1;

            gameLoop();

            won = false;

        }

    }

public void gameLoop(){

    map = new Maze(Maze[lvl]);

    try {
        map.createMaze();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    bullets = map.getBullets();
    hero = map.getPlayer();
    enemy = map.getGhosts();

    while(GameState.going()){

        updateScreen();

        map.isCollision();

        collision();

        [...]

        try {
            Thread.sleep(20);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

public class GameState {

static int ENEMIE_LIFE = 1;
static int HERO_LIFES = 1;
static int HERO_AMMO = 20;

public static boolean going(){

    if(HERO_LIFES > 0 && ENEMIE_LIFE > 0)
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
}
```

}

As you can see, the textFiles are in a String Array, and in the Frame constructor the gameLoop is created. And I have my if/else statement.

```
if(enemy.isEmpty()){
    won = true;

    GameState.ENEMIE_LIFE--;

    lvl++;
}
```

This if statement is to controle when the enemies are destroyed. The GameState.ENEMIE_LIFE is a static int variable in a separete class. The problem I seem to have is that specific variable doesn't want to increase after the first time.

When the enemies are gone the boolean won = true, GameState.ENEMIE_LIFE = 0 and lvl++ (to increase the int that determines the Maze array index. As you could se, when won = true GameState.ENEMIE_LIFES = 1 and gameLoop is set to start again. But if GameState.ENEMIE_LIFE == 0 the game cannot start again and won = false. I said it works the first time. Is there a way to a more efficient way that works?

Thx in advance.

Comment: What happens, when the level changes from 2 to 3? Just nothing? Or do you have to play the second level once again? What is it?

Comment: Nothing happends. Just because the while loop inside the gameloop stays false, therefore does not update the screen.

Comment: maybe you shold add the while-loop to your question. please post a little bit more code